# Angularjs (select): Show other attribute from array than the one stored in ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have a select input that give me a choice between thoses objects:

```
$scope.items = [{"id": "0", "name": "AAA"},
                {"id": "1", "name": "BBB"},
                {"id": "2", "name": "CCC"}]
```

I need to store the Id and show the name attribute in the select box when it is selected or when the Id has already been stored in the object to be modified.

The object:

```
$scope.object
```

I have this has html code, it stores the selected item Id in $scope.object.itemId without problem but the selected item name doesn't show in the select input when it's selected or has been already selected.

```
<select ng-model="object.itemId"
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items track by item.id">
</select>
```

Note that the select list is correctly populated with the items names.

Thank's for you help!

Comment: remove 'track by item.id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is the best explanation I found by an Angularjs developer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564/#issuecomment-51615589

In short: you can't combine `track by` with `select`. Use either one or the other.

Here's the example that is provided in the link above (copied here for convenience):

There are two different Use Cases:

**1. You want a shiny presentation for an ugly value**

Use value as label:

```
items = [
  {value: 1, label: 'One'},
  {value: 2, label: 'Two'},
]

template = 'ng-options="item.value as item.label for items"'
```

When you change the dropdown, the model is assigned whatever you define in front of the `as`.

**2. You want to iterate over complex objects**

Use track by:

```
items = [
  {id: 1, ...},
  {id: 2, ...},
  {id: 3, ...},
]

template = 'ng-options="item as item.label for items track by items.id"'
```

When you change the dropdown, the model is assigned the `item`. The `track by` expression is only used to associate options with items through the `value` attribute on the `<option>`

Answer (score 1):

Use a typeahead-input-formatter and from that return the value you want displayed as the chosen value. Something like this

```
   <select.... typeahead-input-formatter="itemchosen($model)"
```

and then

```
    $scope.itemchosen = function(id) {

         var theItem = jQuery.grep(items,function(p) { return p.id == id };
         return theItem.name;

   };
```